# How can I return options for an HTML select from a Template Helper in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I thought I could return the options for an HTML select element something like this:

In the Template's .HTML file:

```
  <select id="stateorprovince" name="stateorprovince">
    {{statesAndProvinces}}
  </select>
```

In the Template's .js file (bogus data for now; will replace with US States and Canadian Provinces, at least):

```
Template.addJobLoc.helpers({
  statesAndProvinces: function() {
    return
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  }
});
```

...but it fails to build with a syntax error at the start of the first "option"

If I enclose the options in single quotes, the error is "Unexpected token ILLEGAL'

What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this approach which is better suited than returning HTML from a template helper :

HTML

```
<template name="addJobLoc">
  <select id="stateorprovince" name="stateorprovince">
    {{#each statesAndProvinces}}
      <option value="{{value}}">{{label}}</option>
    {{/each}}
  </select>
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.addJobLoc.helpers({
  statesAndProvinces: function(){
    return [{
      value: "volvo",
      label: "Volvo"
    },{
      value: "saab",
      label: "Saab"
    }, ...];
  }
});
```

Here we're returning an hardcoded array within the helper for the sake of simplicity but you could also return collection data.

Answer (score 1):

In your helper, you need to wrap your return value in quotes.

I would suggest the following changes

Helpers

```
statesAndProvinces: function(){
    return ["Volvo", "Saab","Mercedes"];
}
```

HTML(inside the select tags)

```
{{#each statesAndProvinces}}
 <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapting saimeunt's accepted answer, this is what I ended up with (just to show the complete code).

If you want both U.S. States (and Territories, etc.) plus Canadian Provinces, you can use this in your Meteor apps as-is, except for replacing the Template name of "addJobLoc" with your template name.

I am using the full place name as the "hover hint" for the item, and the two-letter designation as the content (select options).

I got the JSON list of states and provinces from wholypantalones (great moniker, primo!) [here](https://gist.github.com/wholypantalones/9916267).

HTML:

```
<select id="stateorprovince" name="stateorprovince">
    {{#each statesAndProvinces}}
      <option title="{{hint}}">{{abbrcode}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

JavaScript (Helper in *.js file):

```
Template.addJobLoc.helpers({
  statesAndProvinces: function() {
    return [{
      "hint": "Alabama",
      "abbrcode": "AL"
    }, {
      "hint": "Alaska",
      "abbrcode": "AK"
    }, {
      "hint": "American Samoa",
      "abbrcode": "AS"
    }, {
      "hint": "Arizona",
      "abbrcode": "AZ"
    }, {
      "hint": "Arkansas",
      "abbrcode": "AR"
    }, {
      "hint": "British Columbia",
      "abbrcode": "BC"
    }, {
      "hint": "California",
      "abbrcode": "CA"
    }, {
      "hint": "Colorado",
      "abbrcode": "CO"
    }, {
      "hint": "Connecticut",
      "abbrcode": "CT"
    }, {
      "hint": "Delaware",
      "abbrcode": "DE"
    }, {
      "hint": "District Of Columbia",
      "abbrcode": "DC"
    }, {
      "hint": "Federated States Of Micronesia",
      "abbrcode": "FM"
    }, {
      "hint": "Florida",
      "abbrcode": "FL"
    }, {
      "hint": "Georgia",
      "abbrcode": "GA"
    }, {
      "hint": "Guam",
      "abbrcode": "GU"
    }, {
      "hint": "Hawaii",
      "abbrcode": "HI"
    }, {
      "hint": "Idaho",
      "abbrcode": "ID"
    }, {
      "hint": "Illinois",
      "abbrcode": "IL"
    }, {
      "hint": "Indiana",
      "abbrcode": "IN"
    }, {
      "hint": "Iowa",
      "abbrcode": "IA"
    }, {
      "hint": "Kansas",
      "abbrcode": "KS"
    }, {
      "hint": "Kentucky",
      "abbrcode": "KY"
    }, {
      "hint": "Louisiana",
      "abbrcode": "LA"
    }, {
      "hint": "Maine",
      "abbrcode": "ME"
    }, {
      "hint": "Manitoba",
      "abbrcode": "MB"
    }, {
      "hint": "Marshall Islands",
      "abbrcode": "MH"
    }, {
      "hint": "Maryland",
      "abbrcode": "MD"
    }, {
      "hint": "Massachusetts",
      "abbrcode": "MA"
    }, {
      "hint": "Michigan",
      "abbrcode": "MI"
    }, {
      "hint": "Minnesota",
      "abbrcode": "MN"
    }, {
      "hint": "Mississippi",
      "abbrcode": "MS"
    }, {
      "hint": "Missouri",
      "abbrcode": "MO"
    }, {
      "hint": "Montana",
      "abbrcode": "MT"
    }, {
      "hint": "Nebraska",
      "abbrcode": "NE"
    }, {
      "hint": "Nevada",
      "abbrcode": "NV"
    }, {
      "hint": "New Brunswick",
      "abbrcode": "NB"
    }, {
      "hint": "New Hampshire",
      "abbrcode": "NH"
    }, {
      "hint": "New Jersey",
      "abbrcode": "NJ"
    }, {
      "hint": "New Mexico",
      "abbrcode": "NM"
    }, {
      "hint": "New York",
      "abbrcode": "NY"
    }, {
      "hint": "Newfoundland and Labrador",
      "abbrcode": "NL"
    }, {
      "hint": "North Carolina",
      "abbrcode": "NC"
    }, {
      "hint": "North Dakota",
      "abbrcode": "ND"
    }, {
      "hint": "Northern Mariana Islands",
      "abbrcode": "MP"
    }, {
      "hint": "Nova Scotia",
      "abbrcode": "NS"
    }, {
      "hint": "Northwest Territories",
      "abbrcode": "NT"
    }, {
      "hint": "Nunavut",
      "abbrcode": "NU"
    }, {
      "hint": "Ohio",
      "abbrcode": "OH"
    }, {
      "hint": "Oklahoma",
      "abbrcode": "OK"
    }, {
      "hint": "Ontario",
      "abbrcode": "ON"
    }, {
      "hint": "Oregon",
      "abbrcode": "OR"
    }, {
      "hint": "Palau",
      "abbrcode": "PW"
    }, {
      "hint": "Pennsylvania",
      "abbrcode": "PA"
    }, {
      "hint": "Prince Edward Island",
      "abbrcode": "PE"
    }, {
      "hint": "Puerto Rico",
      "abbrcode": "PR"
    }, {
      "hint": "Quebec",
      "abbrcode": "QC"
    }, {
      "hint": "Rhode Island",
      "abbrcode": "RI"
    }, {
      "hint": "Saskatchewan",
      "abbrcode": "SK"
    }, {
      "hint": "South Carolina",
      "abbrcode": "SC"
    }, {
      "hint": "South Dakota",
      "abbrcode": "SD"
    }, {
      "hint": "Tennessee",
      "abbrcode": "TN"
    }, {
      "hint": "Texas",
      "abbrcode": "TX"
    }, {
      "hint": "Utah",
      "abbrcode": "UT"
    }, {
      "hint": "Vermont",
      "abbrcode": "VT"
    }, {
      "hint": "Virgin Islands",
      "abbrcode": "VI"
    }, {
      "hint": "Virginia",
      "abbrcode": "VA"
    }, {
      "hint": "Washington",
      "abbrcode": "WA"
    }, {
      "hint": "West Virginia",
      "abbrcode": "WV"
    }, {
      "hint": "Wisconsin",
      "abbrcode": "WI"
    }, {
      "hint": "Wyoming",
      "abbrcode": "WY"
    }, {
      "hint": "Yukon",
      "abbrcode": "YT"
    }]
  }
});
```